# What is $\int \log x \,\, \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus

Today one of my friends asked  me what's the $$\int \log x \,\, \mathrm{d}x$$ and I was unable to answer. I think we just take the Taylor series and integrate it . Is that all or something else.

*Note: I am grade $11$ student so I don't know any advanced calculus and all hyperbolic functions.*

Comment: Write your integral as $\int 1. \ln x dx$ and apply integration by parts.

Comment: Oh so its $xlogx-x$

Comment: $$\displaystyle\bbox[1ex, border:solid 1.5pt #e10000]{\int \log x \,dx = x\log x - x + c} \impliedby \dfrac{d}{dx}\big(x\log x - x + c\big) = \log x + \dfrac{x}{x} - 1 = \log x$$

Comment: A grade 11 student who first thinks of Taylor series and term-by-term integration instead of integration by parts. Well that's new.

Comment: Im new to whole integration and being here for a while i saw many people using the word taylor series so i thought so

Comment: The spoiler here (that Parts should be used) is that $\log x$ has a simple derivative.

Answer (score 4):

Partial integration does help here. We have
\begin{align*}
  \int \log x \, dx &= \int 1 \cdot \log x \, dx \\
     &= x \log x - \int x \cdot \frac 1x \, dx \\
     &= x \log x - x+C.
\end{align*}

Comment: you forgot the +C

Answer (score 4):

A little longer is with a change of variable:

$$\int\ln x\mathrm d x\to\begin{matrix} x=e^y\\\mathrm d x=\mathrm d e^y=e^y\mathrm d y\end{matrix}\to\int ye^y\mathrm d y=ye^y-e^y+C=x(\ln x-1)+C$$

Of course this answer is "worst" than a direct manipulation as other answer shows but I want just to illustrate a "different" way to do it.

Comment: I liked use of log property